# tsql help with concatenting several fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have address columns that i would like to concatenate even if only one field is not null.

for example

```
street,city,state,zip
null,null,AL,36609
```

Currently, my sql statement is like this:

```
select street + ',' + city + ',' + state + ',' + 'zip as address
```

so the sample record above gives me null for address. is there an easy way to show whatever is not nulll?

so the example record above would return:

```
AL, 36609
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(
     ISNULL(','+street,'')
    +ISNULL(','+city,'')
    +ISNULL(','+state,'')
    +ISNULL(','+zip,'')
    ,2, 500) AS address
FROM    table
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
select
    isnull(street + ',', '') +
    isnull(city + ',', '') +
    isnull(state + ',', '') +
    isnull(zip + ',', '')
```

This relies on the standard NULL behavior where any operation on NULL returns NULL.  So street + ',' will return NULL if street is NULL.  The [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) operator will then choose the empty string instead.

For more information about NULL concatenation, see [SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx).  (This option will always be enabled in a future version.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):

```
SELECT
  COALESCE (street, '') +
  COALESCE (city, '') +
  state +
  zip AS address
```

An alternative is to use [`ISNULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx):

```
SELECT
  ISNULL(street, '') +
  ISNULL(city, '') +
  state +
  zip AS address
```

Comment: @p.campbell - Quite right. I assume the leap from `,` to `+` is too much too... Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @temp table (street varchar(100) null,city varchar(100) null, state char(2) null, zip varchar(10) null)
insert into @temp (street,city,state,zip) values (null,null,'AL','36609')

select ISNULL(street + ', ','') +  ISNULL(city + ', ','') + ISNULL(state + ', ','') + ISNULL(zip,'') from @temp
```

will return you

```
AL, 36609
```

**EDIT**

This is not pretty, but seems to work for a variety of null placements:

```
declare @temp table (street varchar(100) null,city varchar(100) null, state char(2) null, zip varchar(10) null)
insert into @temp (street,city,state,zip) values (null,null,'AL','36609')
insert into @temp (street,city,state,zip) values (null,null,'AL',null)
insert into @temp (street,city,state,zip) values ('Acacia Avenue',null,'AL',null)
insert into @temp (street,city,state,zip) values ('Acacia Avenue',null,null,null)

select
  case 
    when city is null and state is null and zip is null then ISNULL(street, '')
    when state is null and zip is null then ISNULL(street + ', ','') +  ISNULL(city,'')
    when zip is null then ISNULL(street + ', ','') +  ISNULL(city + ', ','') + ISNULL(state,'')
    else ISNULL(street + ', ','') +  ISNULL(city + ', ','') + ISNULL(state + ', ','') + ISNULL(zip,'') 
end 
from @temp
```

**RESULTS**

```
AL, 36609
AL
Acacia Avenue, AL
Acacia Avenue

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: IF i just have the state, or any field for that matter except for zip, I get "AL," the trailing comma. Anyway around that?

Comment: Good point, you could use a cascading case statement - it will be ugly I'll knock one up

Comment: @rod, the edit I've just made should do what you are asking for

Answer (score 0):

I'd write it as below :

```
DECLARE @Address VARCHAR(200)
select @Address= isnull(',' + street, '') + isnull(',' + city, '') + 
isnull(',' + state,     '') + isnull(',' + zip, '') from yourtablename where criteria
SELECT STUFF(@Address, 1, 1, '') AS Address
```

As already pointed out by other members, when you perform any operation on fields having NULL, resultant expression(value) would always be null.